# SOAP client request with username and password in header

Tags: java, wsdl, ws-security

I have the the following Java client for making a SOAP request:

```
package com.example.petstore.test;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;

import com.example.petstore.schema.ProcessUpdateResponse;
import com.example.petstore.schema.SyncProcessDAO;

public class TestUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();        

        // Use the URL defined in the soap address portion of the WSDL
        factory.setAddress("http://192.168.1.4:8080/MySyncService/services/SyncProcessDAOPort"); 

        // Utilize the class which was auto-generated by Apache CXF wsdl2java
        factory.setServiceClass(SyncProcessDAO.class);        

        Object client = factory.create();

        try {        

            // Call the Web Service to perform an operation
            GregorianCalendar gregory = new GregorianCalendar();
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlgregory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregory);
            ProcessUpdateResponse response = ((SyncProcessDAO)client).gatherFunctionAttributes("hello1", "hello2", "hello3", 1, 2, xmlgregory, xmlgregory, "hello4", "hello5");    
             System.out.println("hahahaha");
            System.out.println(response);    

          } catch (SecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

I need to modify this to include a username and password as part of the WS security header. How would I go about doing this ?

In case it is useful I have also attached my WSDL file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="SyncProcessDAOService" targetNamespace="http://example.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="http://example.com/" schemaLocation="my_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="gatherFunctionAttributesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:gatherFunctionAttributesResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="gatherFunctionAttributes">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:gatherFunctionAttributes">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SyncProcessDAO">
    <wsdl:operation name="gatherFunctionAttributes">
      <wsdl:input name="gatherFunctionAttributes" message="tns:gatherFunctionAttributes">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="gatherFunctionAttributesResponse" message="tns:gatherFunctionAttributesResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="SyncProcessDAOServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:SyncProcessDAO">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="gatherFunctionAttributes">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="gatherFunctionAttributes">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="gatherFunctionAttributesResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SyncProcessDAOService">
    <wsdl:port name="SyncProcessDAOPort" binding="tns:SyncProcessDAOServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MySyncService/services/SyncProcessDAOPort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Client Side you need to write below code to pass use/pwd as

```
SyncProcessDAO client = (SyncProcessDAO)factory.create();
Map<String, Object> requestContext =   ((BindingProvider)client).getRequestContext();                              
Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
requestHeaders.put("username", "user");
requestHeaders.put("Password", "pwd");
requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);
```

Please encrypt password before sending to server

Please follow below link for more details for server side changes

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/

if you want to implement jax WS-Security then please follow this link

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html